# Is this a correct implementation of LESS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

**Problem**

Ok so i'm trying to use LESS to allow a CSS called bootstrap.min.css to only apply to one part of my code. As when i apply it globally it screws with my styling.

**Current Implementation**

> My .less defined in header

```
<head>

    <link href="Boot.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css">

</head>
```

> Contents of Boot.less

```
#bootbox
{
 @import (css) "bootstrap.min.css";
}
```

> Usage in body

```
 <div id="bootbox"> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="less-1.7.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

 $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
        var currentForm = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
            if (result) {
                currentForm.submit();
            }
        });
    });

</script>



   </div>
```

This how ever does not apply the bootstrap.min.css to everything in the div id "bootbox".

Am i doing something wrong or have i gone the wrong way about the whole thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the CSS that is generated on your page using F12 tools...

You could treat the CSS file as LESS

```
#bootbox
{
 @import (less) "bootstrap.min.css";
}
```

If you were to Import a .LESS file, it would also give you desired results during LESS compilation.

```
#bootbox
{
 @import "bootstrap.less";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, treating the CSS as Less did the trick! Been struggling with this for a couple hours now.

Comment: @DanCundy CSS is LESS ;)  A linguistic superset.